# Emacs autocomplete: add existing dictionary to a major mode

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

This seems fairly simple at first, but it's pretty frustrating. I'd like to assign existing autocomplete rules (`ac-mode`) to a major mode. E.g. recently I discovered `sass-mode` and I'd like to use `css-mode` dictionary for it. Surely I can just copy and rename the dictionary directory, but that's a pretty ugly (and inefficient) hack.

Any ideas how to mend this in a nice manner?

Comment: Define "autocomplete"? I don't believe standard Emacs uses that terminology, so I'm not sure what you are referring to.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was referring to this one: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoComplete

Comment: what rules.? I think what you meant is sources. what sources you want to add.? dictionaries.??

Comment: Yeah, sry again for messed up terminology. I want to apply `css-mode` dictionaries to `sass-mode`, since `Sass` syntax is valid `CSS` syntax.

Comment: Ah, nevermind, symlinking the dictionary file works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess the "proper" way would be:

1. Create a folder for the dictionary, e.g. `~/.emacs/dict`
2. Copy and rename `css-mode` to `scss-mode`

   - `css-mode` can be fined in autocomplete package directory
3. Add `~/.emacs/dict` to `ac-dictionary-directories`

`(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs/dict")`

This method is useful because it allows you to add words to the dictionary file.

But I did otherwise. I just created a symlink `scss-mode` directly in `autocomplete/dict`